# SharePoint Calendar Question

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, permissions, calendar

I am trying to set permissions on a SharePoint calendar to which a visitor is able to create/edit/delete THEIR OWN appointment, but NOT edit/delete appointments entered by other visitors.

What specific custom permission do I need to set up to do this? I have tried many combinations to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint out of the box **Item-level Permissions** for such requirements.

You can set item-level permissions like below from **List settings > Advanced settings**:

[image]

You can choose "Read access" options as per your requirements.